# How to get image from url and cache it

Tags: java, android, caching, imageview

I'm trying to get image from a url and updating it to an Image view. But the images are not being cached and reload when I scroll down then up

I'm using the following AsynkTask for updating images to ImageView

```
public class GetImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {

    private String url;
    private ImageView imageView = null;
    private CircleImageView circleImageView = null;

    public GetImageTask(String url, CircleImageView circleImageView) {
        this.url = url;
        this.circleImageView = circleImageView;
    }

    public GetImageTask(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        this.url = url;
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }


    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            URL urlConnection = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(imageView != null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
        if (circleImageView != null)
            circleImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't cache the images please suggest an edit to cache the images

Comment: Try Glide or picasso library for better handling https://github.com/bumptech/glide picasso https://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: @AnasMehar It worked. Thanks